# jquery nestable list with set drag and drop condition

Tags: jquery, list, tree

hello I use jquery nestable list plugin where I want two types of list node. one is group and another is position. position type node can be drop under position and group but not in root . and group type node can be drop under only group and root but not in position. and after drop I want parent node information and dragged child information. please also see screen short.

[image]

Comment: please check current code and you can update here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jahidrjs/ptyhk75c/15/

please help me!!!!!!!!